# Return object from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I guess this is a real newbie question but I cant find any answers here, in my java-book or elsewhere.

I'm trying to build a GUI using Swing where I can register different kinds of wine. I want my wine-class (there will be a wine super class and three sub classes: red, white and rose) to consist of both some strings and integers (name, year etc.) and a bunch of objects like Country, District, House and more.

I create the wine object from a JPanel now consisting of a `JTextArea` for the name and a `JComboBox` for the country, I populate my combo box by using a for loop that collects the name variable from the object country that's stored in a arraylist.

Here is my form for rose wine, the others look about the same.

```
class RoseWineForm extends JPanel {

   private JTextField wineName = new JTextField(15);
   private JComboBox countryBox = new JComboBox();

   public RoseWineForm() {
       JPanel line1 = new JPanel();
       setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
       line1.add(new JLabel("Namn: "));
       line1.add(wineName);
       add(line1);

       JPanel line2 = new JPanel();
       line2.add(new JLabel("Ursprungsland"));
       line2.add(countryBox);
       for(Country c : listOfCountries) {
       countryBox.addItem(c.getCountryName());
       }
       add(line2);
  }

  public String getName() {
      return wineName.getText();
  }

  public Country getCountry() {
      return ;
  }}
```

Here is the `ActionListener` that sends the user to the forms

```
class NewWineListener implements ActionListener {
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent a) {
     try {
         JComboBox wineColor = (JComboBox) a.getSource();
         if (wineColor.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {
             RedWineForm red = new RedWineForm();
             int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TestVin.this, red, "Nytt rött vin",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
         } else if (wineColor.getSelectedIndex() == 1) {
             WhiteWineForm white = new WhiteWineForm();
             int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TestVin.this, white, "Nytt vitt vin",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
         } else {
             RoseWineForm rose = new RoseWineForm();
             int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TestVin.this, rose, "Nytt rosé vin",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
         }
     } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TestVin.this, "Fel inmatning!");
        }
    }
```

Here is my country class:

```
public class Country {

private String countryName;

public Country(String countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}

public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}

public void setCountryName(String newCountryName) {
    if ( newCountryName == null || newCountryName.trim().isEmpty()) {
       System.out.println("You have to set a name.");       
    }  else {
    countryName = newCountryName;
    }} 
    public String toString() {
    return countryName;         

}
}
```

My question is: When I select the country name in my combo box how do I return the object and not just the `String` called `countryName` so that I can create my wine object with the variables `String name` and `Country country`?

Hope you can have understanding that there is some swedish in there.

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding just the country name like you are doing now, you will need to add the country object itself, something like this will be fine:

```
public RoseWineForm() {
       JPanel line1 = new JPanel();
       setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
       line1.add(new JLabel("Namn: "));
       line1.add(wineName);
       add(line1);

       JPanel line2 = new JPanel();
       line2.add(new JLabel("Ursprungsland"));
       line2.add(countryBox);
       for(Country c : listOfCountries) {
           //This does the trick
           countryBox.addItem(c);
       }
       add(line2);
  }
```

Then in your class "Country" you will need to override the "toString" method, I believe you are doing it fine, would be a good idea to format your code to make it more readable.

```
public class Country {

    private String countryName;

    //Constructor, getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.countryName;
    }

}
```

And whenever you want to get the country object you have selected, you can just:

```
Country selectedCountry = (Country) countryBox.getSelectedItem();
```

And get the ID, name or any other property you would need for the functionality you wish to implement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works almost I think but I'm doing something wrong because when I create my Wine object I get a null value on Country, I create an object of Wine but the Country variable is null. So I guess that either when I return "selectedCountry" from my RoseWineForm or when I put the Country in my JComboBox information is lost. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post the code on how are you creating the Wine object and assigning the Country value? I do not think that the country information loses when you put it in the JComboBox since the component is displaying the values, isn't it? Please, provide the code on how you are getting your values from the UI to provide you more help.

Comment: RoseWineForm rose = new RoseWineForm();
                 int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TestVin.this, rose, "Nytt rosé vin",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                 
                 if (answer != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
      return;

  } else {

                    RoseWine r = new RoseWine(rose.getName(), rose.getCountry()); 
                    allWines.add(r);
                    allRoseWines.add(r);
                    System.out.println(r.toString());
                }

Comment: And this is the modifications I made to RoseWineForm:

Added : 
private Country selectedCountry = (Country) countryBox.getSelectedItem(); to the constructor.

Added what you instructed to the JComboBox.

And wrote this method:  

public Country getCountry() {
          return selectedCountry;
      }

Comment: First thank you for helping me out!

This is what the method looks like: 
public Country getCountry() { return selectedCountry; }

Comment: I believe that, since you are adding the logic to get the item in the constructor of the form, you are not getting the selected value, but null instead since there are no selected value by the moment the form is being created. I'd say that you can try to change your getCountry method to this: public Country getCountry() { return countryBox.getSelectedItem(); } and get rid of the private method and the selectedCountry variable.

Comment: That didn't work, but I rewrote the method like this: public Country getCountry() { 
          Country selectedCountry = (Country) countryBox.getSelectedItem();
          return selectedCountry; 
      }

And now it works! Thanks again for your help, have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `DefaultComboBoxModel` class since this allows you to dynamically allocate the objects to it. Then in country you need to `@Override` the `toString()` function to return `countryName` so that way when the `DefaultComboBoxModel` object pushes to the combobox it will show the name but it will return object if that makes sense. which in order to set the model you created to the JPanel you can use `countryBox.setModel(<name of DefaultComboBoxModel>)`.